# Exchanging between limit and sum.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\,(n=1,2,\dots)$ is a sequence of uniformly continuous functions, and the infinite series of them uniformly converge to a continuous function $F:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ on $(\delta, 1-\delta)$ for all $\delta>0$. 
Then, define $S_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$.
At this time, is it true including the case in which both side diverge that
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{N\to\infty}S_N(0)=\lim_{x\to+0}F(x) ?
\end{align*}

Especially, I'd like to know for $s\leq 1$, $\eta_s(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{nx}}{n^s}$ diverges as $x→-0$ actually? $\eta_s$ is defined for $x<0$. (This appears in statistical mechanics.)

Comment: $\lim \inf \eta_s(x) \geq \lim \inf \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {e^{nx}} {n^{s}} =\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{s}}$ for each $N$ so $\eta_s(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: I forgot to remark that $\eta_s$ is defined for $x<0$. Thanks.

Comment: My argument works fine for $x \to 0-$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: The claim in this question is incorrect at least in its original form. $f_n(x)=(-x)^{n-1}$ and $F(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ on $[-1,1]$ is a counterexample.

Comment: you are right. That is a counterexample.